# How can I apply style and change the name of the button in Upload Control in HTML( Using MVC here)

Tags: html, razor, file-upload

I am using a normal Upload control in MVC as given below.

```
<input name="uploadFile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
```

My question is how do I change the name of the button from `Browse...` to something else and apply some style to that button?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how do I change the name of the button from Browse...

You can't style or personalize the file input field. Its look will vary between browsers and OSes. There are [some techniques](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) though which you could apply to achieve this goal.

Comment: Wow, Didnt know this! Will try to apply the technique mentioned there, Thanks. And we dont have any other easier methods right?

Comment: @AdarshK, what do you mean by *easier*? As I said you cannot style the file input directly so only workarounds are possible.